# How to use PostgreSQL pgrouting functions to find the shortest path between two geometry points with MOST K edges?

Tags: postgresql, shortest-path, dijkstra, pgrouting

I have set up tables containing vertices and edges (representing airports and the route between them).
Using the following query I'm able to get the shortest path between two points.

```
SELECT p.seq, p.node, p.cost, r.geom as edge_geom, c.name
FROM
pgr_dijkstra(
        'SELECT id, source, target, distance AS cost FROM airport_route',
        (SELECT id FROM airport WHERE code = 'HEL'),
        (SELECT id FROM airport WHERE code = 'LAS'),
        TRUE
    ) AS p
    LEFT JOIN airport_route AS r ON p.edge = r.id
    LEFT JOIN airport AS c ON p.node = c.id
ORDER BY
p.seq;
```

And the result is as follows:
[image: Query result]

**The question is**:

How can I find the shortest path between these two points with most K edges?

> postgis and pgrouting are installed; network topology has been created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research I noticed that Dijkstra can not take any limitation in number of edges by nature; So I had to create an algorithm inspired by Bellman Ford.

For detailed information have a look on the following repository:

https://github.com/majidakbari/flight